# Angular directive cannot be used?

Tags: javascript, angular

1) Created a new directive with angularCLI.

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[scrollable]'
})
export class ScrollableDirective implements OnInit{

  constructor(public el:ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log('its working!')
  }

}
```

2) Angular CLI automatically adds the directive to the app.module declarations

```
import { ScrollableDirective } from './scrollable/scrollable.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    ScrollableDirective
  ],
```

3) Try to use the directive as an attribute

```
<div class="menu-container" *ngIf="menuService.showMenu" [scrollable]>
```

4) Resulting error

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'scrollable' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

I have read the official documentation and I seem to be doing all the right things. I cannot understand what I could have missed and why the directive cannot be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `scrollable` directive without the `[]` bindings:

```
<div class="menu-container" *ngIf="menuService.showMenu" scrollable>
```

`[]` would be if you are passing a value to the directive, but you aren't utilizing any `@Input` values in you directive, so it would not be needed.

The [docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) use the binding brackets `[highlightColor]="'orange'"` because it's expecting a string value from the consumer to specify a color. `@Input` would only be needed if you are needing a value passed to the attribute directive to use in some way.

@Kevin is right that the error is being caused by @Input not being added to the directive configuration, but in this case you don't need it, so avoid the import/export of that decorator.

Comment: Fast response, I'll accept the answer when the site lets me in a few minutes.  Can you provide more reasoning as to why that works?  Following all of the examples indicated that you declare directives with square brackets.

Comment: brackets are used for binding, not declaring (I'll remove my answer, this seems to better address the question)

Comment: You are right that is what the cause of the error was, but in this case as no inputs are needed, it's best to leave @Input out and avoid importing/exporting it.

Comment: @mls3590712 I've updated my answer to hopefully explain why brackets and @Input aren't needed in this instance. If you ever decide to pass values to the directive, which is absolutely doable, you'll need the brackets and `@Input` then. Hopefully that helps!